# Is there a way to let the user input ONLY 3 specific numbers? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, input, integer

I'm trying to create a 2 - 4 player dice rolling game that I want the user or users to choose how many players are going to be playing the game.

I made this to be an input but I only want the user to input a number between 2-4

I have tried using the "try and except" or like "while True" but these two don't work which is a pity.

```
def players():
    while True:
        try:
            numberOfPlayers = int(input("How many players are there? (2-4)"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number from 2-4")

players()
```

This is what I've done so far but it accepts all numbers e.g. 50 and like 100 but I only want the input to be a number from 2-4

Comment: are u trying to make code to only accept 3 separate integers or "2-4"?

Comment: accept 3 separate integers

Comment: There's no built-in method for this, just write `if not 2 <= numberOfPlayers <= 4:`

Comment: oh ok ill try this but put this in the answer section so that I can tick it if it works! :)

Comment: @Barmar made it a comment because it's not really answer-worthy.  It's a simple technique that already appears in many tutorials and other answers.  As such, we likely won't archive it on this site.

Comment: We closed this question because it's essentially the same as that other question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response